# Angular 2 + ionic 2 : filter function dependent from *ngFor on other page

Tags: angularjs, angular, dependencies, angularjs-filter, ionic2

I have a simple ion-list and a filter to display the items that match a certain key:value; I don't know if I did the right way, if there is a better way tell me please.

**LIST.HTML**

```
<ion-content class="listPage">
    <button ion-item [ngClass]="{active: type =='all'}" (click)="filter('all')">all</button>
    <button ion-item [ngClass]="{active: type =='red'}" (click)="filter('red')">red</button>
    <button ion-item [ngClass]="{active: type =='blue'}" (click)="filter('blue')">blue</button>

    <ion-list class="task-list">
        <button ion-item class="task-item" *ngFor="#item of list" [hidden]="isFilter(item.type)">
            <h2>{{item.title}}</h2>
            <p>{{item.type}}</p>
        </button>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

**LIST.JS**

```
export class ListPage {
   static get parameters() {
     return [[NavController]];
   }

   constructor(nav) {
     this.nav = nav;
     this.typeFilter = 'all';

     this.list = [
        {
            "title": "Anastasia T. Benton",
            "type": "red"
        },
        {
            "title": "Adena C. English",
            "type": "blue"
        },
     ]
   }



    filter(itemFilter) {
        this.typeFilter = itemFilter;
    }

    isFilter(itemType) {
        if (this.typeFilter == 'all') {
            return false;
        } else {
            return itemType != this.typeFilter;
        }
    }

}
```

So far it works nice, it shows the right list items when i click the correspondent button.

Now i want to put this "filter" on a side-menu that is on app.js, but then the function doesn't work and i don't know how to fix it.

**LIST.HTML**

```
<ion-navbar *navbar>
  <button menuToggle>
    <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
  </button>
  <ion-title>List</ion-title>
</ion-navbar>

<ion-content class="listPage">
    <ion-list class="task-list">

        <button ion-item class="task-item" *ngFor="#item of list" [hidden]="isFilter(item.type)">
            <h2>{{item.title}}</h2>
            <p>{{item.type}}</p>
        </button>

    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

**APP.HTML**

```
<ion-menu [content]="content">

  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>List Filter</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>

  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
        <button ion-item [ngClass]="{active: type =='all'}" (click)="filter('all')">all</button>
        <button ion-item [ngClass]="{active: type =='red'}" (click)="filter('red')">red</button>
        <button ion-item [ngClass]="{active: type =='blue'}" (click)="filter('blue')">blue</button>
        <button ion-item [ngClass]="{active: type =='orange'}" (click)="filter('orange')">orange</button>
        <button ion-item [ngClass]="{active: type =='greene'}" (click)="filter('greene')">green</button>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-menu>

<ion-nav id="nav" [root]="rootPage" #content swipeBackEnabled="false"></ion-nav>
```

**APP.JS**

```
//i know i need to do something here. about dependencies, but i can't figure out how :/
```

Also I would like to show something (can be a ) when the result from the filter is a empty list.

I started learning Ionic 2 and Angular 2 this week and I'm struggling it. The only thing I know about Angular so far, I learned from "Shaping up with Angular.js" from CodeSchool
I already know a lot about html5, scss, jQuery and some bases on javascript.
I don't know typescript so far.

Sorry for not having a live example, but i don't know how to build one with angular. Otherwise I would do it.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Also, instead of using [hidden], use ngIf to control whether the button is showing or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is move your list data management to a service. ( you can generate an empty service with `ionic g provider service-name` )

your service will have to look something like this:

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';    

  @Injectable()
  export class ListService {       

 constructor() {
 this.typeFilter = 'all';
     this.list = [
        {
            "title": "Anastasia T. Benton",
            "type": "red"
        },
        {
            "title": "Adena C. English",
            "type": "blue"
        },
     ]
   } 

    filter(itemFilter) {
        this.typeFilter = itemFilter;
    }

    isFilter(itemType) {
        if (this.typeFilter == 'all') {
            return false;
        } else {
            return itemType != this.typeFilter;
        }
    }
}
```

In your @App you will inject this service in the providers array:

```
import {ListService} from './providers/list-service/list-service'


@App({
  templateUrl: 'build/app.html',
  providers: [ListService] ,
  config: {} // http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/config/Config/
})
class MyApp {

constructor( public listService: ListService ) {

...
```

So now you can use listService in your app template, like:

```
 <button ion-item [ngClass]="{active: type =='all'}" (click)="listService.filter('all')">all</button>
```

To use this service in your List @Page you have to inject it a bit differently; do not declare it in the providers array; instead just do it on the constructor:

```
export class ListPage {
   static get parameters() {
     return [[NavController, ListService]];
   }

   constructor(nav, listService) { ... }
```

Now you are ready to reference listService in your List template, like:

```
<button ion-item class="task-item" *ngFor="#item of listService.list" [hidden]="listService.isFilter(item.type)">
```

Again, make sure you do not add ListService to the providers array in ListPage; this will create a second instance of the service, so you will have two different sets of data (one for the app, one for the page).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did it all but in the end on console i have:

> 408TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getOptional' of undefined

p.s. I use js and not ts

Comment: ah.. i never worked with it ._. it seems pretty confused compared to codepen

Comment: for the record you can use this codepen for small samples http://codepen.io/tlancina/pen/EPBdVE but it won't handle your case. just post your log then.

Comment: i figured out the problem. i was using javascript. with typescript it fixed the problem. Thanks for the help! :D

Comment: yes, you'll find typescript is easier to develop with; if you are using sublime as an editor (which you should) you get intellisense with the typescript package

Comment: The project changed and now i'm working with javascript, not ts. All works, the only difference is when i call the service on @page, i have to declare it on providers array also. Thank you again :) –